# The best way to expand the dimension of a numpy array so as to meet different requirements

Tags: python, numpy

I have a mask `m` of shape `[bz]` and a dictionary `d` contains many different ndarrays, e.g. `d['s'].shape=(bz, 84, 84, 4)`, `d['r'].shape=(bz, 1)` and etc. All have the same first dimension of size `bz`, but the rest may vary. I want to expand the dimension of `m` properly so that I can multiply `m` by the values in `d`. For example, I may want `m` to be of shape `[bz, 1, 1, 1]` in order to multiply `d['s']` and `[bz, 1]` for `d['r']`. I can think of a nasty while-loop solution as follows.

```py
for k, v in d.items():
    if m.shape != v.shape:
        reshaped_m = m.copy()
        while len(reshaped_m.shape) < len(v.shape):
            reshaped_m = reshaped_m[..., None]
        d[k] = v * reshaped_m
```

I'm looking for a better solution, thanks.

Comment: Look at the code for `np.expand_dims`.  It uses `reshape` with a tuple constructed from several pieces.  Or you could index with something like `idx = (elipsis,)+(None,)*n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do -

```
for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = (v.T*m).T
```

So, we are basically pushing the first axis to the end, so that `v` becomes broadcastable against `m`. Then, multiply with `m`. Finally, pushing the last axis back to the front.

There could be different ways to permute those axes, but `transposing` is the simplest one.

If the mask has more dimensions than `1`, we would need to transpose `m` too. Hence. for that case, it would be `d[k] = (v.T*m.T).T`.

---

Another way would be to reshape `m` and then multiply with `v` -

```
for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] =  v*m.reshape(m.shape + (1,)*(v.ndim-m.ndim))
```

---

And another with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = np.einsum('i...,i->i...',v,m)
```